# Remove tabs bar from CTabCtrl when there is only one page

Tags: mfc

i have created a `CTabCtrl`inside a `CDockablePane`, and i have added only one page, then there is no need to show the tabs bar.
how can i remove the tab bar when there is only one page ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can do this in WinForms by trapping the `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` message, [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4409941/366904). I can't get it to work in MFC, though. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried a subclass of CTabCtrl that had been added to a dialog. It never processed this message, unless I sent it manually.

Comment: `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` does work in MFC. Normally you need to call `CTabCtrl::AdjustRect` to find out where to put the child pages, this generates `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` message. I don't think the message is generated automatically in WinForm. But this solution is too complicated, it's easier to avoid calling `CTabCtrl::AdjustRect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the tab and use `CTabCtrl::AdjustRect` to reposition the child pages. For example:

```
void CMyDialog::show_tab_bar(bool show)
{
    tab.ShowWindow(show ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);

    CRect r;
    tab.GetWindowRect(&r);
    ScreenToClient(&r);
    tab.AdjustRect(FALSE, &r);

    page1.SetWindowPos(0, r.left, r.top, r.Width(), r.Height(), SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    page2.SetWindowPos(0, r.left, r.top, r.Width(), r.Height(), SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    ...

    page1.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

Alternatively you can use `CTabCtrl::DeleteAllItems` if you want the tab borders to be visible always.

```
void CMyDialog::show_tab_bar(bool show)
{
    tab.DeleteAllItems();
    if (show)
    {
        tab.InsertItem(0, L"Page 1");
        tab.InsertItem(1, L"Page 2");
        ...
    }

    CRect r;
    tab.GetWindowRect(&r);
    ScreenToClient(&r);
    tab.AdjustRect(FALSE, &r);

    page1.SetWindowPos(0, r.left, r.top, r.Width(), r.Height(), SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    page2.SetWindowPos(0, r.left, r.top, r.Width(), r.Height(), SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
    ...

    page1.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
but when i hide the `CTabCtrl` also the page hides even if  i use `page1.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)`.
Any other suggestions?
Thanks you @Barmak Shemirani

Comment: Apparently you have created the page dialogs as children of tab control, which is wrong to begin with. Use `tab.DeleteAllItems()` in this case. I already showed that as an alternative. But don't calculate child window position the way I did.

Comment: Thank you @Barmak Shemirani